# Circular definition of rationals.

Tags: definition, rational-numbers

If we define rational numbers as

> *A rational number is any number that can be fraction $\frac pq$ of two integers $p$ and $q$, with the denominator $q$ not equal to zero.*

But integers themselves are rational numbers of the form $\frac p1$ where $p$ is an integer. So the definition becomes circular. How do we avoid this?

Comment: That is not how we define the integers.

Comment: The way *this* definition is written, you need to have defined the concept of *number* first.

Comment: Yes but even if we define them in some other way how can we conclude that integers are rational numbers?

Comment: in some place is needed the concept of isomorphism to make it completely formal, and maybe some axioms of ZF

Comment: @AkshatSharma The point is that the subset of the rationals that you allude to is *ring isomorphic* to the version of the integers you are used to.  We don't distinguish between rings that are isomorphic.  "The integers" do not only exist as one single set.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way consists of:

- To define integers in a way that doesn't use rational numbers.
- To define a rational number as an equivalence class $\bigl[(a,b)\bigr]$ of elements of $\mathbb Z\times(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})$, where the equivalence relation is$$(a,b)\sim(c,d)\text{ iff }ad=bc.$$

This approach also avoids another problem in what you wrote: it does not assume that there is a general concept of number.

Comment: But it raises the as big problem that integers are *not* rationals. Instead we have to make some leap to note that the rationals contain a canonical copy of the integers and we can *identify* the integers with their image under that canonical inclusion. Some authors may even go all the way and *replace* the canonical image of the integers in the rationals with the original integers ...